# Can you reference buffers in command mode?

Tags: command-line, buffers

I know about `%` and `#`, which reference the filenames of the current and previous buffers in command-line mode. Is there any way to similarly reference other buffers?

For example, let's say that `:ls` gives me:

```
1 #h   foo.txt
2  h   bar.txt
3 %a   baz.txt
```

...and I want to use a command to the effect of:

```
:!pandoc foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt -o out.pdf
```

Only with a bit less typing. I would imagine something along the lines of

```
:!pandoc b1 b2 b3 -o out.pdf
```

So. Is there anything like this? Is there an addon somewhere, or some handy bit of vimscript I could use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
:!pandoc #1 #2 #3 -o out.pdf
```

This is mentioned briefly in the help at `:h :_#n`.

If you need the full path to the file (say, because some of the files are in different directories), you can append `:p` like so:

```
:!pandoc #1:p #2:p #3:p -o out.pdf
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't sure how to find this in the help documents (`:h #` brings up info about the normal-mode object). I might sometimes need the complete filepath, which according to the help would be `:!pandoc #1:p #2:p #3:p -o out.pdf`.

Comment: @evilsoup, a good trick to know is `Ctrl-D` when typing a help command.  It lists the possible completions.  Try typing `:h #` and then pressing `Ctrl-D`.  Also note that unlike shell autocompletion, this lists any help topic containing the typed substring—it doesn't have to be at the start of the help topic name.

Comment: @Wildcard thanks for the tip, that'll come in handy I think.

Comment: You can also reference current buffer filename with `%` and [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5182852/673852) file with `#`. E.g. `!kdiff3 % #` will run `kdiff3` command with the filenames of current buffer and the alternate one.